# use javascript through vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net-2010, registerstartupscript

i want to write message through  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method . but am getting error in this statement.

```
my code
-------
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "temp", ("<script language='javascript'>alert(' No data in the database  ');</script>")), False)


error(in particular position)
-----
 , False)   error   -   end of the statement expected


 scriptmanager     Error 'System.Web.UI.Page.Friend ReadOnly Property ScriptManager As System.Web.UI.IScriptManager' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.
```

Help me to correct the problem. am new to javascript

Answer (score 3):

Strange message, can you try the following:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
sb.Append(@"alert(' No data in the database  ');");
sb.Append(@"</script>");

If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript")) Then
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "JSScript", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: am using vb.net. please help me to convert it in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim js As String = "alert('TGIF!!.')"
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "popup", js, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old tread but thought i would mention that i had the same problem using code from a .net 3.5 in 2.0, So it is finding a different definition of ScriptManager that is not the same as what I needed.

Once i changed the project to 3.5 it worked fine.